# How to update a location in a map in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, geofire

I wanted to update my location in android studio but it doesn't even show where my location is and when I try to exit the map the app crashes. I even tried storing the location in firebase database but even that is not happening
Also it also gave me warning that some of these are depreciated  can that be the  reason why that error is happening?
this is my code

```
public class DriversMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ActivityDriversMapsBinding binding;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleapiclient;
    Location lastlocation;
    LocationRequest LocReq;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityDriversMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        assert mapFragment != null;
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){
        mGoogleapiclient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleapiclient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
        lastlocation=location;
        LatLng latLng=new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
        String userID= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Drivers Available");
        GeoFire geoFire=new GeoFire(reference);
        geoFire.setLocation(userID,new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        LocReq = new LocationRequest();
        LocReq.setInterval(4000);
        LocReq.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleapiclient, LocReq, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull  ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleapiclient, this);
        String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("driversAvailable");

        GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
        geoFire.removeLocation(userId);
    }

}
```

this is wht it showed in my logcat

```
2021-06-23 14:12:10.233 4430-4430/com.example.deliveryapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.deliveryapp, PID: 4430
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.example.deliveryapp/com.example.deliveryapp.DriversMapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: GoogleApiClient must not be null
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: heyy @AlexMamo i edited it  now

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: it doesnt throw any error but like my location isnt detected

Comment: @AlexMamo r u talking abt the logcat error?

Comment: In code, at which line of code does it occur?

Comment: it doesnt show the error 
but like it doesnt show my location @AlexMamo